# exception with gsub in R

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to replace all strings with "other", EXCEPT the ones starting with numbers in the following example:

```
strings <- c("test.5","5.test","6.test","test","test")
```

I found that the code below replaces only the strings starting with numbers:

```
gsub("^[0-9].+", "other", strings)
"test.5" "other"  "other"  "test"   "test"
```

However, I am really confused about how to reverse the statement, so that everything EXCEPT these strings is replaced.

Desired answer would be

```
 "other" "5.test"  "6.test"  "other"   "other"
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's considered good manners to upvote and checkmark a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 sub('^[^0-9].*', "other", strings)
 #[1] "other"  "5.test" "6.test" "other"  "other"
```

Comment: @ZMacarozzi  No problem.  The idea is to match the first character that is not a number.  Using  `^[^0-9]`  ensure that we are matching the first character that is not a number.

Comment: You should read the ?regex page's section on character classes.